# React app is blocked by CORS policy with Nginx proxy server

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am getting **cors** issue in one of the Poc I am working on.Backend Apis are behind the Nginx proxy server and if any try to hit proxy, Browser is complaining Cors issue.

If I try with the actual endpoint of API services,I don't see any errors.I am assuming, I have to fix this at the **Nginx** level rather than adding proxy config in react app level.
I have tried most of the solutions available in online forum. Could anyone please help me if I have missed anything to rectify error .

React app is running on port 3000 and Nginx is running on port 80.

Proxy settings in **Default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=1s ipv6=off;

    location /products/ {
    
                add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
                add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
               return 204;   
            }   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                access_by_lua_file /usr/local/openresty/lualib/auth.lua;
                proxy_pass http://items-ms:9212/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                #  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
        location / {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
               return 204;   
            }
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}
```

Error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/products' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field 
authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight 
response
```

I am attaching docker-compose file and nginx.conf and default.conf [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-2yhexg?file=nginx%2Fdefault.conf,docker-compose.yaml,node%2Fapp.js,nginx%2Fnginx.conf)

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it looks like your request is sending a header called `authorization`, but that is not included in the config you've provided.

YOu might need to change this line:

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
```

to this:

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
```

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend looking more closely at the network info in the network tab of your browser, and looking at the `OPTIONS` preflight request that the browser is sending.

Comment: Hi @Willow Thanks foor that . I tried  adding authorization header which lead to other errors . But i solved those errors . Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution on above issue:

1. Add headers in NGINX proxy default.conf
2. Add cross origin header and assign value to either * or respective IP:Port

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";

add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
```

3. Enable cors either in reverse proxy or in backend . If we have them in both places ,Browser complains with error